# find replace vbscript excel specific cell

Tags: excel, vba, replace, vbscript, find

I want to make use of the find replace Vbscript function on a specific cell inside excel. My Current code is:

```
Dim myxl
Dim mywb
Dim mysh

Set myxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myxl.Visible = True 
myxl.DisplayAlerts = False
myxl.EnableEvents = False

'20160412 BM open the workbook
Set mywb = myxl.Workbooks.Open(mysrcfile, True, False, , , , , , , True)

'20160523 BM open the sheet
Set mysh = mywb.WorkSheets("General")

'The parameters in the following order for: what, replacement,lookat,  searchorder, matchcase
mywb.Sheets("General").Columns("C").Replace "Y", "N", 1, 2,  True 

mywb.Save
mywb.Close false
Set mywb = Nothing
myxl.EnableEvents = True
myxl.DisplayAlerts = True
myxl.Quit
Set myxl = Nothing
```

In this code i managed to let the script look at the whole columns "C". Now i want the find&replacement to be only on specific cells. for example only Cells C1, C2, C4, C11, and some more. Can someone lend me a hand on this?

p.s. I'm new to VBA and new to scripting/programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this. You may write a function to avoid reduplication:

```
mywb.Sheets("General").Range("C1").Replace "Y", "N", 1, 2,  True 
mywb.Sheets("General").Range("C2").Replace "Y", "N", 1, 2,  True 
mywb.Sheets("General").Range("C4").Replace "Y", "N", 1, 2,  True 
mywb.Sheets("General").Range("C11").Replace "Y", "N", 1, 2,  True
```

Comment: And if you try like this: mywb.Sheets("General").Range("C1").Replace "Y", "N"

Comment: Your answer should do it... but it is still not working :/. Can you try it out with a function?

Comment: Hi. What exactly does not work? If you write >Range("C1").Replace "Y", "N", 1, 2, True < in the immediate window doesn't it change it from Y to N?